# Enable required field validator inside gridview in a particular row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have implemented Grid View as below lines of code

```
<div  class="overflowX">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0" OnRowCommand="grdView_RowCommand" runat="server" CssClass="table">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Save It">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiration Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpirationDate" style="padding:12px 5px;" placeholder="(mm/dd/yyyy)" CssClass="datepiker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ValReqExpD" Enabled="false" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Expiry Date cannot be Blank." ControlToValidate="txtExpirationDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="ValRegExpD" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtExpirationDate" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid Expiry Date ." ValidationExpression="([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])([-/.])([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-/.])(19[5-9][0-9]|20[0-4][0-9])">
                        <b>Enter a valid Renewal Date</b>
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="ValCmpSD" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtEffectiveDate" ControlToValidate="txtExpirationDate" ErrorMessage="Expiry Date should be greater than Effective date" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Now I want that When user will check boxes of a particular row, then the required feild validation "ValReqExpD" should be enabled in that particular row...

```
    protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkbox");

            RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Row.FindControl("ValReqED");

            if (chk.Checked == false)
            {
                  rfv.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

I have tried the above code but it is not working !!!

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probelm with your current code is that gridView's `RowCommand` event is raised when any event like button click etc is raised but since your Checkbox control is not doing anything this event will not trigger anything.

You can attach a `CheckChanged` event with your `CheckBox` control and enable autopostback like this:-

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkbox_CheckedChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Then in the code behind, find the RequiredFieldValidator (present inside the row in which the checkbox is checked) and enable it like this:-

```
protected void chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CheckBox chkbox= sender as CheckBox;
   GridViewRow currentRow = chkbox.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
   RequiredFieldValidator rfv = grdCustomer.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex]
                                      .FindControl("ValReqED") as RequiredFieldValidator;
   if (chkCustomer.Checked)
   {
      rfv .Enabled = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to **add server event on CheckBox** control of Change event fire.
2. Then fire of **checked event** of Checkbox you need to **enable/disable RequiredFieldValidator** server control.